# WPF DataGrid calculations

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am very new to WPF and C# so please help to solve this problem.
I have a `DataGrid`, columns as follows: "One", "Two", "Multiply".

The idea that I am entering number "One" or "Two" and get result in the column "Multiply".

When I write my code and debug it, I can see that the value of the property is being re-calculated. However, I would not display in my last column unless I push space bar, or click on my last column.

Here is the code:

```
public class Numbers : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private double _one;
    private double _two;
    private double _multiply;

    public double One
    {
        get { return _one; }
        set { _one = value; UpdateValue(); }
    }

    public double Two
    {
        get { return _two; }
        set { _two = value; UpdateValue(); }
    }

    public double Multiply
    {
        get { return _multiply; }
        set { _multiply = value; UpdateValue(); }
    }

    public Numbers(double pOne, double pTwo)
    {
        _one = pOne;
        _two = pTwo;
        _multiply = GetMultiply(); 
    }

    private void UpdateValue()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("One");
        OnPropertyChanged("Two");
        OnPropertyChanged("Multiply");
        _multiply = GetMultiply();
    }

    private double GetMultiply()
    {
        return _one * _two;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}

public class Collection :  ObservableCollection<Numbers>  
{
    public ObservableCollection<Numbers> Numbers { get; set; }

    public Collection()
    {
        Numbers = new ObservableCollection<Numbers>();

        Numbers.Add(new Numbers(1, 2));
        Numbers.Add(new Numbers(2, 2)); 
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="StockData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" LostFocus="StockData_LostFocus" >
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number One" Width="100" Binding="{Binding One, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number Two" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Two, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Multiply, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:C\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: It seems the setter of the `Multiply` property should be made private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting multiply after raising PropertyChanged event, so UI won't get notification that value has been changed.

Set Multiply and then raise PropertyChanged event:

```
private void UpdateValue()
{
    _multiply = GetMultiply();
    OnPropertyChanged("One");
    OnPropertyChanged("Two");
    OnPropertyChanged("Multiply");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works. So simple... i spent 3 days trying to understand how to make it work. ,

Comment: The recommendation does work , however i dont understand why the order of items in the method is important. if you could explain, or direct me to further reading that will be appreciated. (as i mentioned im very new to WPF and C#) PS: may thanks anyway.

Comment: Whenever any binded property is updated we have to raise PropertyChanged event to notify UI that property has been changed and it should update itself. So, property changed event should be raised always after property is set to correct value. In your case Multiply is set after property changed has been raised for it. Hence, you don't see updated value on UI.